# How to replace a part of substring in Python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a text like

`"Euro Style = $12,345,67, US Style = $12,345,67, $1,234"`

and I want to replace the string to

Output:

```
Euro Style = $12,345.67, US Style = $12,345.67, $1,234
```

i.e. whenever a currency is there, replace comma with dot when currency has 2 digits at the end.

I tried using regex, but somehow I am missing something.

```
add = "Euro Style = $12,345,67, US Style = $12,345,67, $1,234"
print(re.sub(r'([,][0-9]{2,}\B)+','.\2',add))
```

I am getting incorrect output as

```
Euro Style = $12.5,67, US Style = $12.5,67, $1.4
```

Comment: what do you get?

Comment: added to the question

Comment: Try [`,(?=\d{2}\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/ZqcHH3/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
re.sub(r'(?<=\d),(?=\d{1,2}(?!\d))', r'.', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V7a23D/2).

**Details**

- `(?<=\d)` - a digit must be right before the...
- `,` -  comma that should be followed with...
- `(?=\d{1,2}(?!\d))` - 1 or 2 digits (`\d{1,2}`) not followed with another digit (`(?!\d)`).

[Python test](http://rextester.com/DAZH78453):

```
import re
s="Euro Style = $12,345,67, US Style = $12,345,67, $1,234, $12,124,345,456 $0,89  $12,345,678"
print(re.sub(r'(?<=\d),(?=\d{1,2}(?!\d))', '.', s))
# => Euro Style = $12,345.67, US Style = $12,345.67, $1,234, $12,124,345,456 $0.89  $12,345,678
```

Note that in case your numbers are never glued to `_` or letters, you may also use a little simpler regex with a word boundary:

```
(?<=\d),(?=\d{1,2}\b)
                  ^^
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V7a23D/3).

Or even - if you do not care if there is a digit before `,` or not:

```
re.sub(r',(\d{1,2})\b', r'\1', s)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V7a23D/4).

And finally, if you need to also change `$12,212,12345678` to `$12,212.12345678`

```
re.sub(r',(\d{1,2}|\d{4,})\b', r'.\1', s)
```

See yet [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V7a23D/5).

The `(\d{1,2}|\d{4,})` is an alternation group that matches either 1 or 2 digits or more than 4 digits, thus eliminating 3 digit chunks followed with a word boundary.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! it is failing when my string is "$0,89" but I think i can fix this...

Comment: It also fails if the string has $12,345,678. The last `(\d+)` part matches any number of digits.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a bunch of solutions to also fix potential issues in other edge cases.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
re.sub(r',(\d{2}\D)', r'.\1', add)
```

`{2,}` indicates 2 or more numbers. As you want to match exactly 2, you need to give `{2}`. Using \D just to match anything else apart from a digit. Hope this helps! –

Comment: thanks but this is again failing for string like '$1,234,567,89'

Comment: Just realized that this wouldn't match if any $0.89 at the end. Have to change the \D to \B/\b. That again depends what other characters might occur.